# What does "out loud" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> There are also powerful network effects created by these
>   conversations, whether they’re between corporate communicators
>   and employees, or peers asking and answering questions. Having **“out
>   loud”** conversations for employees to discover and join multiplies the
>   information exchange value.

I don't think that it mean "speak loudly" here.

Comment: I think it's also about giving employees the opportunity to speak out loud and feel heard. I think it has more than just they literal meaning here.

Comment: OK. I think you are right. it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speak

> **out loud**

is to speak loud enough so that people who are not part of your conversation can **overhear** it.

Your passage is probably using it as a metaphor for some sort of **discussion forum** (chat rooms, town halls, company gatherings) where people from different parts of the company and different disciplines can join and contribute to a discussion.

In this context **out loud**  has the meaning **to be public** so people can become aware of the optics being discussed.